# ngx-Image-Cropper: how to define width when loaded and before cropped

Tags: angular

Say I have a huge image 6000 px x 4000 px, how can I make it take up only 250 px in width in my .html?

tried followings not working:

```
<image-cropper width="50px"...>

<image-cropper [resizeToWidth]="250"...>
```

Note I don't want to predefine aspect ratio, I know `resizeToWidth` is for after cropped.

Comment: `[resizeToWidth]="200" ` should work. Try it again.

Comment: @dasunse `[resizeToWidth]` is for resiz**ed** one, not the one user can work on. Good demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think outside of the box use old trick, simply use a `<div>` to surround the cropper:

```
<div #cropContainer style="display: block; width: 250px"><image-cropper ...></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-image-cropper-example)

`[resizeToWidth]="200"` should work. Try it again.